# Is there a name for the algebraic structure of all real matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

I know there are matrix rings, but what do we call the structure of the set of ALL real matrices, with the usual sum and product? We are looking for a kind of algebra whose operations aren't defined for each pair from the base set.

Comment: Linear category?

Comment: To spell out Sam Hopkins comment, a linear category is a category where each $\text{Hom}(A,B)$ is equipped with the structure of a $k$-vector space, and composition $\text{Hom}(A,B) \times \text{Hom}(B,C) \longrightarrow \text{Hom}(A,C)$ is bilinear. The category whose objects are the vector spaces $\mathbb{R}^1$, $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbb{R}^3$, etcetera, with $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ being the $m \times n$ matrices is thus a linear category.

Comment: It's also a small category, since objects form a set. Hence a small linear category.